Is Soota a dwija caste?
Child born from Kshatriya father and Brahmin mother is called as Soota.
I want to know if Soota is dwija caste or not ?

No, they are not twice born

Suta is a base born (apasada) or a Varna Sankara not a Dvija.See the verses given below:

Manu Smriti 10.10. Children of a Brahmana by (women of) the three
(lower) castes, of a Kshatriya by (wives of) the two (lower) castes,
and of a Vaisya by (a wife of) the one caste (below him) are all six
called base-born (apasada)
10.11. From a Kshatriya by the daughter of a Brahmana is born (a son called) according to his caste (gati) a Suta; from a Vaisya by females
of the royal and the Brahmana (castes) spring a Magadha and a Vaideha.
10.12. From a Sudra are born an Ayogava, a Kshattri, and a Kandala, the lowest of men, by Vaisya, Kshatriya, and Brahmana) females, (sons
who owe their origin to) a confusion of the castes.

The term "confusion of castes" is a translation for Varna Sankara. When the mother's Varna is higher than that of the father the children born to them are all Varna Sankaras of different types. And Suta is one of them.

They are mentioned as Varna Sankaras (whose Varna can not be properly determined) which itself means they are out of the Varna system hence not a Dvija not even Sudra. @river
